# Multiprocessing in python qgis?

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, parallel-processing

When i try to do mutliprocessing in python Qgis it doesn't work

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Lock
import multiprocessing

def name1(l,i):
    print i

if __name__=='__main__':
    lock=Lock()
    for i in range(5):
        print (i,'process start')
        process=multiprocessing.Process(target=name1,args=(lock,i,))
        process.start()
```

The above code it's working perfectly in eclipse and other IDE's but it is not working with qgis python script

output from eclipse:
(0, 'process start')
(1, 'process start')
(2, 'process start')
(3, 'process start')
(4, 'process start')
1
2
3
4
0

But in pyqgis there's no error and no output

Comment: It works in the Python console of QGIS

Comment: Expand on "doesn't work". Error messages, unexpected behavior, etc.

Comment: I was running the code it doesn't give me any output

Comment: How do you run your code? Which version of QGIS? In the QGIS console, `__name__` is `console`, so your `if`-condition will be false and your code will not get executed. If you remove your condition, you might be successful.

Comment: QGIS version 2.10.1-Pisa. If I remove __name my qgis is removing and I am getting errors and new qgis is opening and says its not a layer

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to comments requesting clarification.  It is unfair for those who would help you to need to scan comments for critical details.

Comment: So you are running it from the console?  What does it say is not a layer?  Can we see the exact error message?